# Probability of infinitely nested events

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a countable set $\{A_i\}$ of events such that $A_{i+1}\subset A_i$. Is it always true that $\Pr[\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i]=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \Pr[A_i]$?

I am particularly interested in the case where the intersection is empty, as could be if the $A_i$ were open sets. If the intersection is empty, does that imply that the limit of the probabilities is zero?

I ask this because I am trying to reach a contradiction in a proof I am writing, and have arrived at a countable set of nested events whose infinite intersection is empty, but all of which have probability greater than some $a>0$. I think this must contradict some kind of axiom, but I don't know much about probabilities of infinite intersections and such.

Comment: yes, its always true. in any finite measure space.

Comment: Yes it is always true https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above